# Multiprocessing of tasks with unknown execution times

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, distributed-computing, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a task graph which I've applied a scheduling algorithm to. The algorithm maps a task to a processor and a start time while respecting some conditions (precedence order, a processor can only handle one task at a time, tasks may not be interrupted etc).

There are two types of tasks, big ones and small ones. The problem is I don't know any of the tasks execution times but I want to use the schedule to compute all tasks in a homogeneous multiprocessing environment. Right now I'm just using some arbitrary weights for each task (like 5 time units for a big task and 1 time unit for a small task).

Is there a way to account for this in python? Some type of trigger that tells the runtime system when it's allowed for a task to be computed?